# Program Freezes When Inserting A New Node To A Linked List

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, infinite-loop

I've made a function to insert a node to a linked list while preserving the list. However, after inserting 2 elements, if the next element is higher than all the others, the program seems to loop infinitely. My conditions show allow the program to break the loop if something happens but it doesn't;

Here's the function. Note that head is a pointer to the first element in the list and is NULL if the list is empty:

```
//defines the node structure
typedef struct node{

int n;
struct node* next;
}node;

bool insert_node(int value)
{
int t=0;


//If list is empty
if (head==NULL){
    node* first = malloc(sizeof(node));

    //error checking
    if (first==NULL)
        return false;

    head = first;
    first->n=value;
    first->next=NULL;
    t=1;
}

else{
    node* body=malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (body==NULL){
        t=9;
        return false;
        }

    body->n=value;
    node* ptr=head;
    node*pre=head;

    //putting new node into list
    while(t==0){
        //error checking
        if (ptr==NULL)
            break;

        //insertion
        else if (value<=ptr->n||ptr->next==NULL){
            body->next=ptr;
            pre->next=body;
            t=1;
        }

        //next node
        else if(value>ptr->n){
            pre=ptr;
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }

        //If all goes wrong
        else 
            t=9; //breaks loop
        }
    }

if (t==1)
    return true;

return false;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you run it in the debugger, stop it when it is in the loop, and see what is going on?

Comment: I did. It runs through and ignores all my if statements and even the else statement and runs again.

Comment: Computers do not ignore "if" statements.  Check why your conditions are not what you expect.

Comment: I did check them. I even added the else statement so it would break the loop. But it doesn't. In GDB, the program does past the lines with the else if statements, I never see the else statement then the function is ran again.

Comment: Try putting printf statements inside each "if" and "else" you are concerned about.  Make sure you compile with no optimization (no -O or -O2 or anything like that), and with debugging symbols (with -g).  I assure you the program doesn't "go past" your if blocks unless the conditions are false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the case where the entry that you are adding needs to be at the head of the list.  Right now you only add to the head when the list is empty.  That is handled by changing the if as follows:

```
if (head==NULL || value < head->n){
    node* first = malloc(sizeof(node));

    //error checking
    if (first==NULL)
        return false;

    first->next=head;
    first->n=value;
    head = first;
    t=1;
}
```

Now that the addition to the beginning of the list is taken care of, the else needs a change to get pre and ptr initialized correctly and the insertion condition needs to be changed as follows:

```
node* ptr=head->next;
node* pre=head;

//putting new node into list
while(t==0){
    //insertion
    if (ptr==NULL || value<=ptr->n){
        body->next=ptr;
        pre->next=body;
        t=1;
    }

    //next node
    else if(value>ptr->n){
        pre=ptr;
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }

    //If all goes wrong
    else 
        t=9; //breaks loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems as though my logic was a bit off. I needed to check when to add to the head of the list, in between then the end. Thanks a lot for clarifying, the code works.